# How to do integration with non-square matrix?

Tags: integration, matrices

I am not sure how to do the following integration with a non-square matrix $A$. By Google search I could get results only for square matrix. But for non-square matrix $\det(A)$ does not exist. So how to do the following?

$\int Ax \: dx$ = ?, where $A$ has dimension $n \times p$ and $x$ has dimension $p \times 1$

Comment: It's essentially a column vector of dimension $n\times 1$ , maybe you gotta integrate it like that of a vector?

Comment: "$dx$" is the volume element in $\mathbb{R}^p.$    Also, $Ax$ is a vector valued function, i.e.  $F:\mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}^n,$ defined by $F(x)=Ax.$    The only way this makes to me is to integrate each components of $Ax$ over some subset of $\mathbb{R}^p.$

Comment: You forgot the domain of integration, without which your integral probabli is not finite $\frown$.  Also, multiplying by a matrix is a liear transformation, so just move $A$  out of the integral.